# Examples of Complicated Online Tools

Tags: web-app

I'm looking for some good examples of interactive online tools that help you complete a complicated process.

IE, turbo tax online does a really good job of this, but I'm looking for other examples.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean complex. Complex is often unavoidable, complicated is undesirable. Complex: a whole made up of complicated or interrelated parts. Complicated: difficult to analyze, understand, or explain.

Answer (score 1):

I would visit a few web-based Medical Records tool (EMR) sites for demos. Any health-care related tools are pretty complex and fascinating in terms of sheer amount of problems being solved for.

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll research that specific landscape, but are there any EMR sites in particular you've seen that were really well done?

Comment: Coincidentally I've heard that EMR tools tend to be UX nightmares even considering the complexity of the tasks. I don't use them myself but a friend of mine loathes Epic EMR and often used it as an example in an HCI course.

Comment: http://www.practicefusion.com/

Comment: and http://www.clinicyou.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Survey Monkey](http://www.surveymonkey.net), which is a really good and clear interface to a process that could be complex. It makes the process of putting together a survey really easy.